# Moving QWidget in Qt 5.15, cursor stuck at 0,0 of widget

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I'm trying to move a QWidget by intercepting the QMouseEvent, I end up with this :

```
void MyWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *evt)
{
    if(!ui.bar_horizontalFrame->underMouse()|| evt->button() != Qt::LeftButton) return;

    if(ui.bar_horizontalFrame->underMouse())
    {
        oldPos = evt->globalPos() - evt->pos(); //QPoint
    }
}
void myWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *evt)
{
    if(!ui.bar_horizontalFrame->underMouse()) return;

    const QPoint delta = evt->globalPos() - oldPos;

    move(delta);
}
```

issue is that no matter where i first press on the frame object, the widget origin (0,0) will move to current cursor position (so the cursor will be on the top left corner). How can I have it so the widget origin doesn't move to cursor position ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You are doing:

```
if(ui.bar_horizontalFrame->underMouse())
{
    oldPos = evt->globalPos() - evt->pos(); //QPoint
}
```

You got to

```
if(ui.bar_horizontalFrame->underMouse())
{
    oldPos = evt->globalPos() - frameGeometry().topLeft();
}
```